# How to make split work? have some kind of translate and edit issue with Chinese

Tags: python, split

I just want to split the string word with '\ue', but it didn't look different.
I know it's some kind of tanslate and edit mistake.How to make it work ? PLZ

Cannot upload code with Chinese so I upload a picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO1So.png

Comment: Why can't you upload code with chinese?

Comment: I don't know.It showed my code is spam :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried it with a raw string? Like

```
word = r'YOURWORD'
splitted = word.split(r'\ue')
```

Comment: r converts your string to a raw string in which \BLA is not an operator for string formatting like \n \t. Maybe there are problems between chinese and these operators, but i dunno

Comment: I have another question.
If I have many str e.g. 'MYWORD' and I need to split them automatically which means I can't type r one by one.
What else I can do?

Comment: You can store it in a variable. Say
list_of_words = ["one", "two", ""three]
for word in list_of_word:
   raw_word = fr"{word}"
   splitted = raw_word.split("someSplitStr") 
should work, but i didn't test it

Comment: And I think, that you can close this thread by marking my answer as accepted :)